# Z3 Output of get-value

Tags: z3

I have a problem with the generation of model values through get-value.
If I try to get the value of an array, I will get a value
containing internal z3 constants which are not printed. I know that
get-model would print those constants but I would like to stick
to using get-value.

Here is an example (I tried it on rise4fun):

```
(declare-const b (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a (Array Int Int))
(assert (= (store a 1 2) b))
(check-sat)
(get-value (b a))
```

returns:

```
sat ((b (_ as-array k!1)) (a (_ as-array k!0)))
```

The output with get-model is the following:

```
sat (model (define-fun b () (Array Int Int) (_ as-array k!1)) (define-fun a () (Array Int Int) (_ as-array k!0)) (define-fun k!0 ((x!1 Int)) Int 0) (define-fun k!1 ((x!1 Int)) Int (ite (= x!1 1) 2 0)) )
```

It contains the value of k!0 and k!1. Is it possible to substitute these in the values for a and b ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation with Z3's modeling of arrays. 
get-value isn't guaranteed to give meaningful results for arrays.

Comment: What I'm interested into is actually just the substitution of k!1 and k!2 values inside into a or b like:
(b (_ as-array ((x!1 Int)) Int (ite (= x!1 1) 2 0)) ))
So, is it possible or do you plan to implement such a thing ?

Comment: I just tried running that same input through the latest version (master from source) and it says ((b (store ((as const (Array Int Int)) 0) 1 2))
 (a ((as const (Array Int Int)) 0))), so there are no k!i's anymore. Did you just change that or was that changed to fix other problems?

Comment: Wow, great ! I will look into last version. Thanks !